# Tabbed Menu in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, layout

I am creating a new layout design for a site. In the header there is a tab design that I would like to render different partials in a specific div. For example

```
<div class="pages">
<div id ="pages_header">
<div class="menu>
<ul>
<li>Tab1</li> (click to render partial)
</ul>    
</div>
</div>  

<div id="side_bar">

</div>

<div id="pages_content">
    <div class="content">
        <RENDER PARTIAL HERE>
        </div>
    </div>  

</div>
```

Here when you clicked Tab1 it would render a partial inside "pages_content"

I can see there are many ways to do this... for example I can use Bettertabs or http://www.simonecarletti.com/code/tabs_on_rails/

However what is the best way to do this, so that I can provide external URL's that will render the correct partial in the right place, along with changing the title of the page to help with SEO. For example www.mysite.com/products/view/product_1 (would link to product_1 partial inside the div "pages_content"). Ideally - it would be fantastic to load these partials using AJAX so they could animate? And with the tabs being highlighted as active.

Would be really interesting to hear what everyone views are on this, as I said I can see multiple ways to do this - would just be good to do the best one! Especially for SEO.

Update:
Would link_to_remote or content_for be useful?

Comment: hey I am sure this must be possible in Rails, has any one got a suggestion at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i actually used Jquery tools... which is a great Javascript library that allows anchored links in tabs.

Answer (score 0):

IMO the best option is use standard anchors and then in jQuery add them function `click` that reload page content with AJAX. If you do that way then if someone with disabled JavaScript visit your site then it will be possible for him/her to navigate over page (the same is about web spiders). It's not good idea to navigate over website only with AJAX.

Comment: Yes. I would iterate over all anchors in menu and add them DOM `click` functionality that will load content with AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

`link_to_remote` is gone in Rails 3, so I wouldn't use that. What you could do is something like, make the tab view in jQuery-UI and have each of the links make an AJAX request asking for show.js.erb and use JavaScript to determine what HTML to add to the DOM. Alternately, Take if naming and SEO is super-important, you can use something like the `pjax_rails` gem.

Comment: what would you use as syntax for a link to render a partial inside the pjax div?